# Two 'identical' databases: One reports 'foreign key may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths' when app starting one does not

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have an MVC code first EF6 SQL Server application which has been running for some time.

Recently, I downloaded the live database from Azure to my local environment (Bacpac and import). With that database I get an error

> Introducing Foreign Key constraint ...may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths...

which appears to be well known.

Note that the only difference is the database and the connection string, the code is identical.  In short the standard answers don't seem to apply.

However, I do not get this with an earlier version of the same database (also downloaded from Azure).  According to a somewhat older version of SQLExaminer, the two databases are identical in structure (apart from a few changes to stored procedures). In particular none of the foreign keys are different.

I have the feeling that I encountered this same error last time I worked in this project and somehow found an answer. I have no idea what that might have been though.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Iain

Answer (score 0):

> 'Introducing Foreign Key constraint ...may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths...

That error means that you are attempting, and failing to create a FK constraint in the database.  So the databases may have *started out* identical, but your app is attempting to change it, perhaps through a Migration.

Comment: Thanks, David.
.As far as I can tell / remember there are no migrations in the system.  The foreign key which it is complaining about is already present in both databases.
I believe that the app started with a database and I added EF through code first.  

In one of my utilities, I have an option to create an edmx file which I vaguely think is related to the solution of the problem.

I think that, in EF there is a table which describes the EF structure and this could be different in the two databases. HOwever, I can't see any such table.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I'm an idiot (again).  I added a fluent entry in the model to specify that key was not cascade on delete and all of a sudden, it worked with the new database. The definition in the DB is still the same for both databases, but ...

So it's working, but I don't really understand why one worked and one didn't.

Iain